# Connect main OPC UA server to secondary OPC UA server

Tags: server, opc-ua

Is it possible to connect an OPC UA server to another OPC UA server, in order to redistribute its data?

In fact, I have a small device which runs a small OPC UA server that exposes some data. The device is running in a private network. Then I have the main OPC UA server accessible from the internet, where I would like to view some of the small device's data, together with some more generic data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, you just need a server that has this feature. It's not a standard part of OPC UA that any server will be able to do.

One option would be to use KEPServerEx's client driver.

Comment: Is the VPI / VFI extensions concept that we see in OpenOPC UA part of the OPC UA standard or is it specific to this implementation of the standard?

Comment: @PedroFerreira why are you asking this unrelated question in the comment?

Comment: Because it can be a possible solution, I guess. But not sure if its part of the OPC UA standard.

Answer (score 0):

OPC UA is a server-client architecture. Therefore, you cannot make two servers talk to each other directly. There must always be an OPC UA client implementation between them. Yes, KepServerEX does support this feature as having an OPC UA Client Driver out-of-the-box. However, you can implement your own little OPC UA client between the servers as a gateway too, which may suit your solution better I believe.

Comment: Is the VPI / VFI extensions concept that we see in OpenOPC UA part of the OPC UA standard or is it specific to this implementation of the standard?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand this will be possible by using an OPC UA Aggregation Server as main server (which is accessible from the internet).

You could test it with the open source [UA-NetStandard Aggregation Server](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/tree/master/SampleApplications/Workshop/Aggregation).